# Identify same values and assign code to them using ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

There is the attribute table the FID_lote_teste fields and selecao both integer.

[image: table]

The selecao field receive zero (0) if the FID_lote_teste field number does not exist in memory.

For example:

First row: selecao gets 0 (zero) because the number 2 from FID_lote_teste field does not exist in memory;

Second row: selecao gets 0 (zero) because the number 3 from FID_lote_teste field does not exist in memory;

Third row: selection receive 1 (one) because the number 2 from FID_lote_teste field already exists in memory;

(...)

6th row: selecao gets 0 (zero) because the number 7 from FID_lote_teste field does not exist in memory;

7th row: selecao gets 0 (zero) because the number 8 from FID_lote_teste field does not exist in memory;

8th row: selecao receive 1 (one) because the number 7 from FID_lote_teste field already exists in memory;

(...)

How do I fill in the selecao field with the field calculator following this algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question before, sorry cannot find it.
Use field calculator expression, python on field "selecao":

```
d={}
def GroupOrder(groupID):
  if groupID in d: d[groupID]+=1
  else: d[groupID]=0
  return d[groupID]
```

## --------------------------

```
GroupOrder( !fid_loat_teste! )
```